# How can i get itemId or ItemName from Firebase RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView Adapter. I need to click on an item in this RecyclerView and get his ID or name ("Audi") and then pass it to the new Activity using intent.putExtra() How can i get id or name "Audi"? Below you can see my code, but it doesn't work :(

```
private var dbRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Cars").child("Models")

inner class ViewHolder(val binding: CarsListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(CarsListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    with(holder) {
        with(carsList[position]) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(image).into(binding.ivCar)
            binding.tvCar.text = this.name

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(itemView.context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)

                val carID = dbRef.ref.key.toString()
                Log.d("MyTag", carID)

                itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return carsList.size
}
```

[image: Audi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "name" property holds the value of "audi", which is almost the same as the key of the node, then you should put this "name" as extra information in your Intent object:

```
val intent = Intent(itemView.context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("name", name)
itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
```

Where "name" is a property within the Car object, as "image" property is inside the following line of code:

```
Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(image).into(binding.ivCar)
```

What remains to be done, is to make the first letter capital:

```
audi -> Audi
```

If this is not what you want, then you should also store the ID of the car like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Cars
       |
       --- Audi
            |
            --- image: "https://..."
            |
            --- name: "audi"
            |
            --- id: "Audi"
```

And then simply use following lines of code inside your adapter class:

```
val intent = Intent(itemView.context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("id", id)
itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
```